# When did "serie" become obsolete in English?

Tags: etymology, historical-change

Why is ***series*** both singular and plural in English? In the other languages I am familiar with, *serie* is the singular. This includes Spanish, French, German, and Italian.

However, it is *series* (in a row) in Latin
, although I have also seen the singular used in some texts.

The only source ([Webster’s 1913 edition](http://www.websters1913.com/words/Serie)) that mentioned ***serie*** in English use says it is an obsolete form.

When did it become obsolete? Going back to 1600,  [Ngrams is essentially useless in this case.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=serie%2Cseries&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1600&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cserie%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bserie%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BSerie%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BSERIE%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cseries%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bseries%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BSeries%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BSERIES%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Bear in mind that, prior to about 1850, dictionaries did not exist as an authoritative description of English spelling and definitions.  Writers and printers used whatever spelling 'felt right" to them.  In the particular case of "series" things also get confused because, by definition, the word refers to a plurality of items, even if there is only one series.

Comment: It needs to be noted that one must now be wary of using the word "serie", lest it unintentionally provoke a response from from your iPhone.

Comment: Regarding "although I have also seen the singular used in some texts", the noun *series* is fifth declension, so the nominative case of the singular is *series*, but the ablative case in Latin is *serie*. So the Latin for "in the series" is *in serie*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My impression is that "serie" is not exactly "obsolete" so much as it is more stigmatized now than it was in the past (maybe a similar example would be the use of "I" in contexts like "between you and I"). Although I associate singular "serie" with non-native speakers, I believe it is also used by some native English speakers in the present.

It's not clear to me that *serie* was ever the usual form of this word in English. The Oxford English Dictionary has examples of singular *series* from as early as 1618. The OED entry for *serie* says "Often criticized in usage guides from the mid 20th cent. (and earlier in N.E.D.: see quot. 1884) as incorrect or nonstandard, and still not common."

As you mentioned, *series* is used as a singular in English because that is the singular form of the word in Latin. There are many words where English uses a fully Latin spelling but French or another Romance language uses an adaptation: e.g. English *thesis* vs. French *thèse* or Italian *tesi.*

Comment: Actually *thesis* might not be a good example of a Latin word.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: *thesis* was taken into English from Latin. The Latin influence can be seen in the plural form, which is *theses* and not e.g. "theseis". Its ultimate origin being Greek doesn't really make a difference to my point as far as I can tell.

Comment: OED doesn't mention Latin **at all:** "Etymology: < Greek θέσις putting, placing; a proposition, affirmation, etc., < root θε- of τιθέναι to put, place."

Comment: @AndrewLeach: the etymology section of that entry is pretty short and doesn't mention Latin, but consider the context of the earliest citations, such as a 1398 translation of the Latin work "De proprietatibus rerum". There are *some* English words from Greek that were not transmitted via the medium of Latin (I think "koine" is an example), but it seems very unlikely to me that *thesis* is one of those. Note also that I didn't actually say it is a "Latin word", just that it is a Latin *spelling.*

Comment: What about usage of the term “in serie”? There seems to be [some support](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22in+serie%22&lr=lang_en&tbs=lr:lang_1en&tbm=bks&prmd=ivn&ei=jL9PXLi1Bozi8wWs5J_YDQ&start=10&sa=N&biw=375&bih=627&dpr=3) for this, analogous to *in specie* (ignore the references in the link to “Series A” and the like).

Answer (score 1):

The complete Oxford English Dictionary reports several things of note. First, that despite first appearing (with the meaning you use) in the written record in 1840 *serie* has been criticised since at least 1884 as being non-standard usage. Additionally, there is a quotation from 1940 pointing to the "mistaken" use of *serie* and *specie*.

From those observations I think one can reasonably conclude that *serie* was always non-standard in British English and that it became obsolete almost as soon as it appeared.

Noteworthy is that in Chaucer's *Knight's Tale*, the word *serie* appears with a slighly different meaning, and again seems to have become obsolete almost immediately.