# Is the word "serie" used in English? (as a singular of "series")

Tags: word-usage, grammatical-number, latin, technical, is-it-a-word

As a continental, I would normally use *serie* to describe a single set, and *series* to describe multiple sets:

- I own a BWM 1 Serie, but I own a collection of 5 Series
- My favourite TV serie is The Simpsons, but I also like other series

In English, *series* is normally singular (like in the Latin etymon *seriēs*), e.g. BMW 1 Series.

> **a** :a number of things or events of the same class coming one after another in spatial or temporal succession 
> // a concert *series* 
> // the hall opened into a *series* of small rooms 
> **b** :a set of regularly presented television programs each of which is complete in itself 
> *[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/series)*

However, I have also come across *serie* for the singular, *e.g.* in this [JuPyteR Notebook](https://github.com/OpenMined/TenSEAL/blob/main/tutorials%2FTutorial%202%20-%20Working%20with%20Approximate%20Numbers.ipynb) on computing on tensors using FHE (1st sentence).

Is it ok to use *serie*? Are there specific contexts in which it is permissible?

Comment: German and French have depluralized the Latin *series* to get *Serie* and *série*.  This is ungrammatical in English and Latin, where the singular of *series* is *series*.

Comment: @PeterShor Thank you, I confirm this also for Dutch (and Zeeuws). I looked further, if English follows Latin, the only correct way is when it is ablative, as in: in serie.

Comment: Related: [When did "serie" become obsolete in English?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/483198/when-did-serie-become-obsolete-in-english)

Comment: The words "serie" doesn't appear in the link. It was likely a typo.

Answer (score 5):

There is no such word as *serie* in English. *Series* is a singular noun, derived from Latin, which just happens to end in 's'.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what would be the plural of series?

Comment: The same. We don't say 'serieses'.

Comment: _OED_ lists the word _serie_ with the meaning "A single series (in various senses), as distinguished from series used as a plural; (also) a member of a series." but adds that it is often criticized as nonstandard or incorrect.  The citations given are either about how it would be correct or incorrect in usage. Although, I agree that native speakers wouldn't use it in colloquial speech.

Comment: You are right of course but I fail to understand why people don't just look stuff up in reliable dictionaries. Serie, indeed. Nowadays, that's Siri. [guffaw]

Comment: @KateBunting Exactly. And we don't say "sheeps" or, usually, "fishes" either. Some English words have no plural form.